# how to set initial value or default value in date field?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a date picker in angularjs and bootstrap but I am facing a few issues:

- initial date is not set
- when I am trying to open one date picker why does it open all the date pickers?

Here is my code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/elrOTfEOMmUkPYGmKTdW?p=preview

```
$scope.dateOptions = {
  maxDate: new Date(2020, 5, 22),
  minDate: new Date(1970,1,1),
  startingDay: 1
};
function disabled(data) {
 return true
}

$scope.open1 = function() {
  $scope.popup1.opened = true;
};

$scope.formats = ['dd-MMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
$scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
$scope.popup1 = {
  opened: false
};
```

Why does it open all date pickers when only one is clicked?  See image below.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> initial date is not set

This is because you are setting the model to a string, but it requires an actual date object.  Do this:

```
date: {
  date: 'date',
  name: d // not this -> moment(d).format('DD-MMM-YYYY')
}
```

> when I am trying to open one date picker why does it open all the date pickers?

Since you're using `ng-repeat` to create multiple inputs, you need to also use separate properties for the `is-open` attribute on each input.  I would suggest adding an `opened` property to the items you're repeating, like this:

```
date: {
  date: 'date',
  name: d,
  opened: false
}
```

Then, on the click event of the button, pass in the repeated item:

```
ng-click="open1(x)"
```

Next, set the `is-open` attribute:

```
is-open="x.opened"
```

Finally, set the `opened` property on it like this:

```
$scope.open1 = function(x) {
  x.opened = true;
};
```

[Here is the plnkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/1CHmq30wSraWtx1xED9f?p=preview)

Comment: can you share the plunker

Comment: @Joy sure, added it to my answer